# Fuzzy-logic-toolkit install problem in Octave

Tags: octave

I am trying to install the Fuzzy-logic-toolkit package in the Octave 5.1.0 using this comand:

```
pkg install -forge fuzzy-logic-toolkit -verbose
```

and tried to sideload also by

```
pkg install fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5.tar.gz
```

but the octave always returns this code:

```
parse error near line 165 of file /home/leo/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5/defuzz.m

  anonymous function bodies must be single expressions

>>>   y_val = @(y_val) if (y_val == max_y) 1 else 0 endif;
                        ^

error: called from
    doc_cache_create>create_cache at line 109 column 20
    gen_doc_cache_in_dir>@<anonymous> at line 143 column 16
    doc_cache_create>gen_doc_cache_in_dir at line 144 column 9
    doc_cache_create at line 55 column 12
    install>generate_lookfor_cache at line 794 column 5
    install at line 223 column 7
    pkg at line 441 column 9
>> warning: load_path: /home/leo/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
warning: load-path: update failed for '/home/leo/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5', removing from path
warning: load_path: /home/leo/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
warning: load-path: update failed for '/home/leo/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5', removing from path
warning: load_path: /home/leo/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
warning: load-path: update failed for '/home/leo/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5', removing from path
```

Anything I can do to solve this issue? I have the same issue in version 4 (that are installed in the `apt install octave` of Ubuntu)

Comment: That's a very odd code addition there. Almost seems like someone wanted to write python code to solve an octave problem. Octave does not support the ternary operator, let alone python syntax. In any case, if you're happy to repackage the toolkit, simply make that line into a proper local function as opposed to an anonymous one, using a normal if block, and it should be fine (assuming no other errors). Alternatively you can try some ugly equivalent oneliner like `y_val = @(y) [0,1]((y == max_y) + 1)` or whatever.

Comment: that line seems to be fixed in the repository from what I see ... no idea why the downloaded version does not include it though. you can download the updated version from the repository I guess

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I solved this problem. I create a folder in my ```/home/octave``` with fuzzy-logic-toolkit name and point the Octave GUI to this folder and made a side loader. That's run... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LeonardoGrando: `made a side loader. That's run...` Could you elaborate on that? It's not clear what you did.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: `... fixed in the repository...` ?? It's 18 months on, and the bogus code remains in the [sourceforge repo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave-fuzzy/files/). I don't know what repo you're referring to - but it's not this one.

Comment: @Seamus that's not the development repository. I'm referring to [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit/ci/00e05af94b3762d2e051ad28fb436da089160f40/). But I agree, it's eggregious that this hasn't been put into a release yet. What's the point of fixing something and then not updating the package ... might be worth writing a nice note to the dev(s). :)

Comment: @Seamus ah, excellent, I spotted you've already opened a bug report on the tracker :) I've left a comment there as well, hopefully the maintainers will release the fix in packaged form soon. In the meantime, if you need to install the fuzzy logic toolkit, you could try installing the development version as per matzeri's answer below. If you have trouble with this I'll be happy to help (just open a new question here on stack overflow).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Thank you! I will follow your suggestion, and most probably will open a new question here on SO to draw more attention to this issue. I'm a bit embarrassed now over my bug report, but I always wonder why these simple things seem to take an eternity to resolve.

Comment: @Seamus given the magnitude and high quality of the octave project, it's sometimes easy to lose sight of the fact that it's a volunteer project, maintained by a handful of unpaid volunteers who mostly do this on any spare time left from their normal day jobs. What happened here is probably as simple as the maintainer forgetting to publish the package after fixing the bug. It happens. And as with other free-software, its quality relies on us users as much as on maintainers. So you did well to bring it to the project's attention, but beyond that, I don't think arguing on there is constructive :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Thank you again. FWIW, here's another view: The project has a [well-maintained page advertising the available packages for Octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/packages.php). It looks nice, no? It says: `These packages are maintained by a community of Octave Forge and Octave developers in a spirit of collaboration.` So - good pictures & good words. But when I searched the bug archives, I saw numerous bug reports for the same problem going back 2 years - all closed. So I wonder - what is going on? I file a bug report designed to get someone's attention. Outcome?

Comment: @Seamus yes, indeed, and Kai discusses this a bit in his reply to your bug report. Octave packages are best thought of as community contributions, and that page was intended to facilitate an official place to feature them, but in essense it is distinct from octave 'the project' itself. In this sense, this is similar to pypi's relationship to the official python project, or matlab file-exchange to matlab. However, that page is a a bit "too-nice", and gives the impression that these are formal octave functionality and maintained by the project. This is further compounded by the fact that (cont)

Comment: some of those packages provide functionality that mirrors matlab toolkits. What happened with this particular bug is that the original maintainer "Linda Markowsky" was contacted (and apparently accepted?) to continue maintaining; the expectation was that she would publish the new release with the bug fixes. But as a result of miscommunication, the package is still unreleased, despite the octave project maintainers attempting to bridge this gap, and the bugfix has stayed in the development stage. This is a rather unusual case. My experience from the bug tracker is that bugs get fixed VERY fast.

Comment: @Seamus as for filing a bug, like I said, you did well (signs of frustration aside, hahah). It has flagged to the maintainers that this isn't a problem with buggy code per se (since this has actually been fixed), and therefore closing tickets as duplicates isn't enough, but a new maintainer needs to be appointed instead. Also, while such a long wait is not typical, note that it is not rare in commercial projects either. I remember I filed a bug in matlab at the start of my PhD which was breaking all my graphs, and it wasn't fixed until the end of my PhD, roughly 3 years later. It happens :p

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: I would be glad to learn that your experience w/ Octave is typical. The sarcastic tone of my bug report was calculated to draw attention - it seemed clear someone was not paying attention, and I was peeved for wasting my time. I guessed that the response might be to "return fire and insult", and indeed it was - Kal closed the report, and implied I was a dolt. Fair enough! - at least we now know that Kal is aware of the problem, and his excuses are in shorter supply. OTOH: If the burden of maintaining a package is too great, wouldn't the proper CoA be to simply remove it?

Comment: @Seamus as per the link in Kai's reply, the situation/steps to take (including removal) regarding unmaintained packages was indeed discussed recently. It is an interesting read for sure. However I'm glad this toolkit has not been removed. I've used it in the past and it's a nice toolkit. I'd be sad to see it go for such a trivial bug. As for "calculated to draw attention", the octave maintainers are very attentive in my experience, but it's inevitable that occasionally things will get missed. Like I said this seems like an unusual scenario (maintainer gone awol, bug fixed but not released...)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: I'm sure you're correct in that this case is an outlier. I guess I just happened to choose the wrong package to get started with. But Kal's response to this can hardly be considered *encouraging* as he closed the bug report, and left the package to frustrate future potential users. You raise a good point re removal of this broken package, but perhaps a note in the "headline page" to the effect that a remedial procedure is required to overcome an error? Maybe Kal will eventually do something about this. Poor guy - he needs a vacation I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The fuzzy logic package has not been update from 2014 so the last one do not build with Octave 5.x

Two possibilities:

1) you take the latest Mercurial code and build from it

```
hg clone http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit octave-fuzzy-logic-toolkit
cd octave-fuzzy-logic-toolkit/
hg archive ../fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5.tar.gz -X ".hg*"
cd ..
octave-cli
pkg install fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5.tar.gz
```

2) download the mercurial code from other source (eg Cygwin source package) and build from it

```
wget ftp://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/sources.redhat.com/cygwin/noarch/release/octave-fuzzy-logic-toolkit/octave-fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.6-0.2-src.tar.xz
tar -xf octave-fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.6-0.2-src.tar.xz
octave-cli
pkg install octave-fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.6-0.2.src/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-hg-0.4.6.tar.bz2
```

Comment: No.2 is very interesting ... how did you find that link? Not even the official publication for the toolkit mentions anything other than the official octave mirrors ... (and I didn't spot anything obvious on duckduckgo)

Comment: Inside job ;-) . I know the content of my cygwin source packages. In general all Cygwin source package contains the original source code and patches  and for several of Octave forge I used the Mercurial code. https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2020-January/009388.html

Comment: Thanks for all of this. It seems to have worked (unless the package was updated since earlier today). I can't help but wonder though: `mercurial is dead` according to reports ([for example](https://www.theregister.com/2019/08/21/bitbucket_mercurial_repositories/))... is this what the Octave maintainers are relying upon?